# block matrix assignment in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

From this mwe:

```
a=np.zeros((5,5))
b=np.zeros((2,2))
a=np.matrix(a)
b=np.matrix(b)
b[0,0]=4
b[1,1]=9
b[0,1]=7
indice=[2,3]
# 1
c=a[indice,:][:,indice]
c=b
print c
# 2
a[indice,:][:,indice]=b
print a[indice,:][:,indice]
```

I get:

```
>>> c
matrix([[ 4.,  7.],
        [ 0.,  9.]])
```

and:

```
>>> a[indice,:][:,indice]
matrix([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]])
```

I do not understand why the values of ***a*** remain zeroes. If a similar operation is done in two steps, everything works fine:

```
>>> for k in range(len(indice)):
...     a[indice[k],indice]=b[k,:]
```

I obtain:

```
>>> a
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  0.,  7.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `a[indice,:][:,indice]` isn't a view into the array but is a separate copy -

```
In [142]: np.may_share_memory(a, a[indice,:][:,indice])
Out[142]: False
```

---

To solve it, we can use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) -

```
a[np.ix_(indice, indice)] = b
```

Verify result -

```
In [145]: a
Out[145]: 
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [146]: b
Out[146]: 
matrix([[ 4.,  7.],
        [ 0.,  9.]])

In [147]: a[np.ix_(indice, indice)] = b

In [148]: a
Out[148]: 
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  4.,  7.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [149]: a[indice,:][:,indice]
Out[149]: 
matrix([[ 4.,  7.],
        [ 0.,  9.]])
```

Comment: amazing ! Thank you.

Comment: Why is this a copy instead of a view? Here is some relevant explainations: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html