# numpy can't assign values to part of a column

Tags: python, numpy

When I want to assign a vector to part of a column in a matrix, it failed. Here is a small example:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(3,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0.12263942, -0.21972043, -0.97263544,  0.10609172],
       [ 0.27012565,  1.0006549 ,  0.80596588, -0.2954019 ],
       [-0.28402912, -2.62405207, -0.52560166,  0.07325703]])
>>> x
array([-0.33707461,  0.66196137])
>>> a[np.array([0,2])][:,2] = x
>>> a[np.array([0,2])][:,2]
array([-0.97263544, -0.52560166])
```

But this works:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(3,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0.45379867,  0.38782073, -0.01432557, -1.03457707],
       [ 1.27650459,  0.4480737 , -1.31625142,  2.00037792],
       [ 0.77420762,  1.20131941, -0.98937721, -0.04921255]])
>>> x2 = np.random.randn(3)
>>> x2
array([-1.82217731, -0.72454628, -0.41954297])
>>> a[:,2] = x2
>>> a[:,2]
array([-1.82217731, -0.72454628, -0.41954297])
```

Why the first example can not work? Do I miss anything?

Comment: Sounds [`relevant`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44262976/3293881).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[]` on an array, it will either return a copy of the array slice you are referencing or be ready to assign to that particular slice.

So when you do `a[slc1][slc2] = stuff`, `a[slc1]` is now a copy of `a`, call it `a_` so that `a[slc1][slc2]` is the same as `a_[slc2]`.

Then you assign to that copy with `a[slc1][slc2] = stuff` same as `a_[slc2] = stuff`.  Which is fine, but you've assigned to a variable that was only temporarily created.

Instead do the assignment within the same assignment

```
a[slc1, slc2] = stuff
```

Or in your case

```
a[[0, 2], 2] = x
```

Check with `(a[[0, 2], 2] == x).all()` will return `True`

Comment: If `slc1` is a slice (':2') the intermittent value is a view and the assignment affects the original array. The copy is produced when the `slc1` is a list or array.  Still indexing with one set of [] is preferable - when possible.